# Is there a way to check if an ISBN number is a valid number before storing into the database

Tags: java, validation, isbn

I was wonder is a there a web service or a database out there that let us programmatically check if the user input is an valid ISBN number before storing it in the database. Or is there a algorithm that allow the programmer to do that

Answer (score 7):

If look on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#Check_digits), they have a simple algorithm to ensure than an ISBN is valid:

```
bool is_isbn_valid(char digits[10]) {
    int i, a = 0, b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a += digits[i];  // Assumed already converted from ASCII to 0..9
        b += a;
    }
    return b % 11 == 0;
}
```

Of course, this doesn't ensure that it's *real*, only possible ;)

EDIT: This includes the ISBN 13 spec: (It's untested, and in the same pseudo-code as the wikipedia function)

```
bool is_valid_isbn(char isbn[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    if(isbn.length == 10) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += i * isbn[i]; //asuming this is 0..9, not '0'..'9'
        }

        if(isbn[9] == sum % 11) return true;
    } else if(isbn.length == 13) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                sum += isbn[i]; //asuming this is 0..9, not '0'..'9'
            } else {
                sum += isbn[i] * 3;
            }
        }

        if(isbn[12] == 10 - (sum % 10)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That algorithm is only apply to ISBN 10 digit, do you know how to do that ISBN 13 digit. The description of the algorithm for ISBN 13 digit seems very complex

Comment: @Harry: I've added an ISBN 13 version (but, it's untested, and also in pseudo-code like the first sample)

Comment: There is an error in your formula. On the fifth to last row you should have `isbn[12] == 10 - sum % 10)` instead. Check this Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit

Comment: You missed something in the Wikipedia article. The check digit is `10 - (sum % 10)` when that result is less than 10, but if it is 10, then the check digit is 0! So the line should be `if(isbn[12] == 10 - (sum % 10) or (10 - (sum % 10) == 10 and isbn[12] == 0)) return true;`

Comment: The code can be simplified a little: `if ((isbn[12] == 10 - (sum % 10)) or ((sum % 10) == 0 and isbn[12] == 0)) return true;`

Answer (score 2):

you might try:

http://isbndb.com/docs/api/

Comment: I don't see that Harry asked for a way to check if a book is known to the ISBNdb.com database?

Comment: and i quote, " is a there a web service or a database out there that let us programmatically check if the user input is an valid ISBN number"  the way i see it isbndb.com is just such a service.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have you try this API before, shsteimer?

Comment: shsteimer: No. ISBNdb.com delivers data for the books in that database. It's does not provide a service to tell if the ISBN is correct or actually assigned.

Answer (score 2):

You could calc the checksum according to this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#Check_digits. That doesn't tell you if there is actually a book with that number but it tells you if the number is correct.

Comment: Thank you. That algorithm is only apply to ISBN 10 digit, do you know how to do that ISBN 13 digit. The description of the algorithm for ISBN 13 digit seems very complex

Answer (score 1):

[Gory details](http://isbntools.com/details.html) here. So you can check the check digit and have a go at deducing what the country (and maybe publisher) are, but I don't see any way of checking there's a real book with that number

Comment: The site provide the code to check that last digit but man it is complex. I will definitely look more into this. Thank you very much +1

Answer (score 1):

To validate just the checkdigit, and not compare against a known list of books, you could use the Apache Commons ISBNValidator class.

```
ISBNValidator validator = new ISBNValidator(); 
assertFalse(validator.isValid("12345678901234")); 
assertTrue(validator.isValid("0-201-63385-X"));
```

Code example from:
https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-validator/+/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/validator/ISBNValidatorTest.java

References:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/ISBNValidator.html

Comment: Works fine ! :) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested in my quick searches on SO try: [idbndb](http://isbndb.com/docs/api/index.html)

Comment: Quote from `jarnbjo`: `No. ISBNdb.com delivers data for the books in that database. It's does not provide a service to tell if the ISBN is correct or actually assigned.` I will take a look at this API. But from what `jarbjo` said, this does not provide the service I need. Thanks a lot for your feedback :D